# Does Warrior's Way have an end?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

I'm tring to defeat 300 foreign kings to get the last *Plaza Ticket*, and while doing so I've conquered the world several times (3-4 as of now), but the game restarts each time and makes me lose all 20 countries.

Is there an actual end? Or does the game restart endlessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game will loop indefinitely if you allow it (so that you can continue to meet other lords).

Comment: Yap, I think you're right. Pretty annoying.